# CentOS 7 - Screen Sharing - VNC - Unknown authType 18

Tags: centos, vnc, centos-7

I'm trying to set up `VNC` to my `Cent OS 7`, I look at [HowTos/VNC-Server - CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) page, unfortunately that applies to Cent OS 6 and as much to Cent OS 7, so I'm back to square one(

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q vino
vino-3.8.1-10.el7.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ netstat -an | grep 5900
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN     
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Whenever I'm connecting from VNC viewer, I'm getting following error:

```
Unknown authType 18
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: [Bug 981984 – Can't connect to Vino, except with Vinagre](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=981984) "Comment 10"

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption
true
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption
false
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```